# I can put my Log in but cannot input my password on PuTTY

Tags: putty

The keyboard functions while I put my log in name, but does not work when I try to put in my password.

Comment: I've only seen a network technician use PuTTY and have not used it myself. If you enter in your username, I believe the password doesn't show for security reasons but that doesn't mean your session won't authenticate.

Comment: If it simply doesn't display any text, that is entirely normal behavior for security reasons. If there is another issue, please [edit] your question and clarify the exact details of the problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 5):

@Christopher Chipps is correct, I'm quite familiar with PuTTY and it will never display the result of you typing into the password field, or even provide any indication that you *are* typing, for that matter.

Enter your password carefully, and it will work as intended.